# VS Emulator - Windows CE Device Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, emulation

I'm trying to learn how to write programs for Windows CE 6.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and have the Windows Device Emulator v3 installed

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7.

When I try to start up the emulator and select "Windows CE" as the device, I get the following error message.

"Connection failed. ActiveSync bootstap initialization failed. Please connect/cradle a real device or download the User-level Windows Mobile Device Center Application from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkid=67763"

I've followed the link to microsoft's site but it just leads to a windows phone page that's of no help to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used an emulator, but IIRC you should be able to [fire up the Device Emulator Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188168%28v=vs.90%29), then Connect and Cradle the emulator.

The other option would be to [use a direct CoreCon connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for debugging by copying the bits to the emulator and running conmanclient2.exe and cmaccept.exe.